# App not visible on iPod after installing through an ad hoc profile

Tags: iphone, installation, distribution, ipod-touch, adhoc

I have build my app with and ad hoc provisioning profile/distribution certificate pair following the instructions from developer program portal. Then I send the binary (.app file) and provisioning profile to one of my peer.

He drag and drop the .app and .mobileprovision files on iTunes and sync his iPod Touch. The iTunes shows the application is installed but I cant see it on the iPod.

Anyone who faced this issue OR have any clue what could have went wrong?

Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you've built an application that will only run on 3.0 devices.

You must set the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to 2.2.1 when you're building the application so that it will run on both 2.2.1 and 3.0 devices. You can still compile against the 3.0 SDK, but you need to set the target to the lowest OS you plan on supporting. You'll find the option in the target build settings.

Comment: Nathan - I checked the deployment target as well as Base SDK. Both are set to 2.2.1. Not sure what is wrong here. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I guess I have kind of figured it out. I created another build today and it worked on iPod as well.
Below are the build settings which I DID NOT change: 
Base SDK: 2.2.1
Deployment target: 2.2.1

While building the the app with distribution/profile pair - I chose Distribution - SDK 2.2.1 (instead of 3.0 which was chosen last time). I tried to install this new binary and it worked.

Does it mean that if I have to make my application available to users with firmware 2.2.1 as well as 3.0 - I will need to select Device 2.2.1 - DistributionProfile while building the app for distribution.

Thanks
AJ

Comment: You should be able to select "Distribution - SDK 3.0" and still be able to install your application on a 2.2.1 device if the deployment target is set to 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

The UDID of that device has to be listed in the developer program portal, and added to the provisioning profile you're using. Then you have to build the app with that provisioning profile (you can check which one it uses in the build results window).

Has the provisioning profile been loaded on the other device correctly? You can check by going to settings, general, and then profiles. The provisioning profile should be listed there.

Comment: Drvdijk - thanks for the comment.

Yes, everything is in place. The iPod Touch on which I was trying to install the app was 2.2.1. 

I tried to install the app on iPhone 3.0 (yes, I already had it listed in the provisioning profile) and worked seamless.

Seems like had to do something with iPod/iPod FW